# Do stuff with cin buffer until empty

Tags: c++, input, buffer, cin

I want to have my program read through the cin buffer until there's nothing left in it to read.

What a lot of places seemed to suggest for this was:

```
while (cin)
{
    cin >> s;       
    //do stuff with s
}
```

However, when I try this, even while the cin buffer is empty, the program just infinitely waits for input and executing the loop.

Doing while(cin >> s) does the exact same thing.

Comment: You have to use the EOF character to indicate end of input (end of cin). You can do this using ctrl-D on linux or ctrl-Z on windows

Comment: I'd suggest `while (cin >> s) { ... }` instead. With the code in your question, the loop will execute one time when `cin` has no more input, which means it will process the last read element twice.

Comment: Also, note that "buffer is empty" is not a condition for the read to fail. If the buffer is indeed empty but the file handle for stdin has not been closed, `cin >> s` will simply *block* until there is more input to read.  As @icedtrees says, you need to use ^D on *nix or ^Z on Windows in order to instruct the shell to close the stdin file handle. At that point, the read will fail and the eof bit will be set on `cin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If standard input is attached to a terminal, the program will wait for input until it gets an EOF condition, which you can send on POSIX systems with a <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You are correct it will wait forever for a new line.

What you could do is this:

```
while(cin >> s){
    //do stuff with s
}
```

What this does is while you can still read into s then do stuff. You will eventually hit the end of the buffer and it will stop.

I believe with the way you are doing it, the computer is thinking that it could still have some information come in.

Comment: I tried this too and it does the very same thing unfortunately.